# Give a RSA public key from a java applet hosted in a web page to a PHP script

Tags: java, php, html, applet, rsa

I have an applet hosted on a Web page. It communicates with a JavaCard and gets the Modulus and the exponent. I regenerate the key in that applet. All this is done on the client side.

My applet have 3 methods to get the public key modulus, the public key exponent and the PublicKey object. How can I use those 3 variables to reconstruc the key on the server side. By PHP if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net)...

(this depends somewhat on the format of the exponent and modulus)

```
<?php
$key =  array(
    'exponent' => new Math_BigInteger($exponent, 256),
    'modulus' => new Math_BigInteger($modulus, 256)
);

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);
$rsa->setPublicKey($key);

echo $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Nice, exacly what I needed. haha just to bad I finished the work using a .jar file instead of incorporating it all in php ... I might make the modification later. Didn't knew about that phpseclib. Thx a lot